# How put string value on column with other column condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and pandas, I'm having a problem:
I want to writte to replace Nan in the "Pays_FR" column with the name of countries in french.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuyGj.png)

I have try : df.loc[df['Pays_EN'] == 'Bolivia', 'Pays-FR'] = 'Bolivie' but no success, maybe because i'm not using the 'inplace=True', and if it's that how i can use it?
Thanks

Comment: make a dictionary of translations (`d = {'Bolivia': 'Bolivie', 'China': 'Chine'}`) and `map`/`replace` the values (`df['Pays_FR'] = df['Pays_EN'].map(d)`).

Comment: Thanks you it's work ! 
I have just add a function str.rstrip()  because i have spaces at the end of my strings: